# When using iota, I am confused

Tags: go

#### What version of Go are you using (`go version`)?

```
$ go version
1.13
```

#### Does this issue reproduce with the latest release?

yes

#### What operating system and processor architecture are you using (`go env`)?

`go env` Output

```
$ go env
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/chezixin/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/chezixin/go/src/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/mr/_x323k891dq9yvmvlgwqf4f40000gn/T/go-build490011880=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

#### What did you do?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
    Name  string
    Port  int
    State State
}

type State int

const (
    Running State = iota
    Stopped
    Rebooting
    Terminated
)
func (s State) String() string {
    switch s {
    case Running:
        return "Running"
    case Stopped:
        return "Stopped"
    case Rebooting:
        return "Rebooting"
    case Terminated:
        return "Terminated"
    default:
        return "Unknown"
    }
}

func main() {
    t := T{Name: "example", Port: 6666}
    fmt.Printf("t %+v\n", t)
}
```

#### Result：

```
t {Name:example Port:6666 State:Running}
```

#### What did you expect to see?

#### What did you see instead?

```
Although the string is rewritten, this is related to State.const.
I am printing a T struct in main. The zero value is 0.
But why do you want to display State:Running

When T.State = 0, why does the program think T.State = const.Running?

I understand this now:
String is an interface type, T.State=0, const.Running=0, the two types are the same, the value is the same, the program will think that the two are equal? Doesn't it distinguish between const and struct at the moment?
According to logic, you should distinguish between const and struct, but the program thinks they are equal. Is this a bug? Or am I getting into a misunderstanding?

Can you tell me how to understand it correctly?
thank you very much
Thank you
```

Comment: Cross posted: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T.State` is of type `State`. This has got nothing to do with the field `T.State` being part of a struct or not. The zero value for the type `State` is 0, which is also equal to `Running`. So when you assign `t` to an instance of `T` with `T.State` left uninitialized, `T.State` gets the zero value, which is `Running`.

As far as I can tell from the code, you seem to have an 'Unknown' value for `State` that is any value other than those that are declared. If you want to print `Unknown` for zero-value of the `State`, change your declaration of constants so `Unknown` gets the zero value (i.e. iota).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, which helped me out of the logical confusion. Thank you.